# tkinter get widget that event got called by

Tags: python, tkinter

Minimal reproducable Example

```
from tkinter import *

def test(event):
    print(event.widget)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")
window.bind("<Motion>", test)

frame = Frame(window, bg="red", width=200, height=200)
frame.pack()
frame.bind("<Motion>", test)

window.mainloop()
```

I want to call the function "test" from different widgets when i move over them. Instead of that, when i hover over the frame, both the window and the frame print that im hovering over the frame, which is not the behaviour i need. Can someone help me achieve the right behaviour?

Comment: Your mouse will (effectively) always be in the root window when the event is triggered. If you want the event to return the same value no matter where the mouse is in the window, what's the point of having the event?

Comment: Youre right, im being unspecific to what my goal is. I'll update the question

Comment: Basically I need to know what object sent the event, no matter where my cursor is located, because it will be called by multiple objects.

Comment: You state what you not need, but what do you need is a leftover.

Comment: if im being honest i dont know what that is supposed to mean?

Comment: What are you looking for, I'm asking. Cause I think a simple binding to `<Enter>` would suit your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion is in the moment of interpreting when the mouse pointer entered the widget or left the widget. Instead of Motion let's use for example Leave and Enter events to better understand what happens.

I have taken the liberty of including some labels that show which widget we enter and left at each moment.

```
from tkinter import *

def test_enter(event):
    enter.set(event.widget)

def test_left(event):
    left.set(event.widget)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
window.bind("<Enter>", test_enter)
window.bind("<Leave>", test_left)

frame = Frame(window, bg="red", width=200, height=200)
frame.pack()
frame.bind("<Enter>", test_enter)
frame.bind("<Leave>", test_left)

label1 = Label(frame, text="Enter")
label1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.4, x= 0.2, y=0.2)
enter = StringVar()
label_enter = Label(frame, textvariable=enter)
label_enter.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.4, x= 0.6, y=0.2)

label2 = Label(frame, text="Leave")
label2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6, x= 0.2, y=0.2)
left = StringVar()
label_left = Label(frame, textvariable=left)
label_left.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.6, x= 0.6, y=0.2)

window.mainloop()
```

Remember that the Frame is inside the Window. I mean that when you enter the Window you have not left root Window, you will continue to be in Window. Or if you enter inside a Label you have not left the Frame.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda to pass the widget when the function is run

```
def test(event, widget):
    print(widget)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")
window.bind("<Motion>", test)

frame = Frame(window, bg="red", width=200, height=200)
frame.pack()
frame.bind("<Motion>", lambda: test(frame))

window.mainloop()
```

You just need to change two lines

```
def test(event, widget):
    print(widget)
```

and

```
frame.bind("<Motion>", lambda: test(frame))
```

Comment: This will work in this specific case, but if you have multiple widgets this likely won't work the way you expect.